# Missing letter 'S' from question titles on SE sites

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, title, firefox

It's been a few days now that I can't see the letter `S` in question titles, when browsing the list of questions of various SE sites. Below is a screenshot from Travel.SE. The title should say "Will U**S** CBP deny me entry because I broke a U**S** lease in 2001"?:

[image: TSE missing S]

Here is another one from Meta.SE (we are suddenly browsing tackOverflow and tackExchange):

[image: MetaSE missing S]

Setting aside the fact that I swear I'm not crazy, just for kicks below is a screenshot of how I see my current question:

[image: MetaSE missing S]

This is by far the weirdest effect I have ever seen. And I'm prepared to bet it's browser dependent. I am currently running Iceweasel 31.7.0 on Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy). I tried chromium on the same distribution and it works fine.

---

I had to reboot my machine and this graphical bug disappeared. Even weirder.

Comment: Can you see the source of the pages? Are all the letter there in the titles?

Comment: @Oded does SE support Iceweasel? (and all other hundreds of Firefox branches?)

Comment: Not really, @Sha, in particular not such an old version. Just curious as to why this would happen (though I would bet a reboot would cure it).

Comment: @Oded Indeed a reboot cured it. It seems to be fixed now. Argh.

Comment: Jeff must have run out of ammo.

Comment: haha, when in doubt - reboot! /cc @Oded ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - naw. Just seen that before - sometimes on linux, some shared libraries in memory could get in memory corruption, causing things like this (browsers use some of the same libraries). So a reboot clears the memory and load a fresh version that isn't corrupt. At least, that's my interpretation of these symptoms.

Comment: @Oded well, for me Chrome on Windows 7 sometimes showing weird things in chat.... Restarting only the browser fix those oddities. :)

Comment: @Oded Did I miss you having exactly 100k?

Comment: I missed the moment, not the experience ;)

Comment: Something like this [happened to me once too](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3537/472), over an extended period but gone after a reboot.  I never figured out what was going on.